# Convert .GRF to Image File in Java

Tags: java, image, hex

I have a Java program that takes a ZPL Graphic Hexcode (.GRF) as input and should generate a JPG or PNG image from it. I have a rough approach, but it doesnt quite work as expected and I dont think its the right path.

[Here](https://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=1&height=1&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%7EDGR%3ABl_Engel.GRF%2C1890%2C15%2C%0A000000000000000000000000000000%0A000000000000000000000000000000%0A00000000000000FFE0000000000000%0A000000000000780003800000000000%0A000000000003000000180000000000%0A000000000018000000030000000000%0A0000000000C0021988006000000000%0A0000000003000F198F801800000000%0A0000000008000F199F800600000000%0A00000000200C0F1998010180000000%0A00000000400E0D999E01C040000000%0A0000000103C60D999F03F010000000%0A000000060FC60FD998031008000000%0A000000080E460FDD98070306000000%0A0000001006E32CCF3F07E701000000%0A0000002003F3EC0007064F60800000%0A00000040033BC000000E0F60400000%0A0000018603B80000000F1AE0200000%0A0000030F01F000000003BBC0100000%0A0000021B01C000FFC000B78F080000%0A0000043900001FFFFE00271D840000%0A0000081FE000FFFFFFE00739820000%0A0000101EE003FFFFFFF80671810000%0A0000218E701FFFFFFFFE006C008000%0A00004307003FFFFFFFFF80C638C000%0A0000472380FFFFFFFFFFC07C784000%0A0000876101FEF07FFFFFF03CEC2000%0A000103C607F1C1C07FFFF811C61000%0A000101EC0FE30300FFF8FC07E41000%0A0002187C1FC700C31FFC2F06300800%0A00063E383F80F0F087FF3383018800%0A00047F1079003FFEC3FFF381878400%0A000C6380F200FFFFF3FF89C19E0400%0A0008F0C1E207FFFFFFFFC0E07C0200%0A00183CC3C3FFFFFFFFFFE0B0700200%0A00101F83C31FFFFFFFFFF898600100%0A00100787803FFFFFFFFFFF88300100%0A00200107807FFFFFFFFFF98C300080%0A0020000E80FFFE001FFFFC0E000080%0A0060001C81FFF80003FFFC0E000080%0A0040001C83FFE00001FFFE0F0000C0%0A0040003C87FFC000007FFF0D000040%0A00C000388BFF801E003FFF89800040%0A00800038E7FF001F001FFF69800060%0A00800078C7FE003F000FFF39800020%0A0080007887FC003F000FFF91C00020%0A008000F80FF8001F0007FF81C00020%0A018000F80FF8001E0003FF81C00020%0A010000F81FF01FFFFF03FFC1C00030%0A010000D83FFFFFFFFFFFFFC1E00010%0A010100D83FFC0FFFFE0FFFC3600010%0A010101C85FF000FFE001FFA2603010%0A010FE1C49FE0007F8001FF9460FC10%0A0107C1C71FE0003F8001FF9C607C10%0A030381C31FE0001F0000FF88607810%0A030281C23FE0001F0000FF88E06810%0A030001C03FE0001E0000FF80E00010%0A030001E03FE0001E0000FF80E00010%0A030001E03FE0000E0001FF81E00010%0A030001F03FE0000E0001FF81E00010%0A030001D05FF0000E0001FF83E00010%0A030001C84FF0000E0001FF06600010%0A010001C44FF0001E0003FE44E00010%0A010000C2CFF8001E0003FE48E00030%0A018000C187F8001E0007FC70E00030%0A018000E087FC001F0007FC61C00030%0A018000E007FE001F000FF841C00030%0A018000F003FE003F001FF803C00030%0A0180007003FF003F803FF807C00060%0A00C0007802FF803F807FE80F800060%0A00C0003E027FE07F80FFD01F800060%0A00C0003F023FF07FC1FF903F800060%0A00E0003CC21FFCFFC7FF10E70000C0%0A0060001E1E0FFFFFFFFE1F0F0000C0%0A0060001E060FFFFFFFFC1C1E0000C0%0A00700C0F0107FFFFFFFC103E000180%0A003018078007FFFFFFF8007C0E0180%0A00303007C003FFFFFFF800F8138380%0A00386F03F003F8FFE3F801F830C300%0A00187603FC07800C003807F03C4300%0A001C4C81FFFE00E1E00FFFE0060700%0A000C1B80FC0007CCFC0007C0638600%0A000E3C007E001F9F3F000F80300E00%0A000610703F003E7F9F801F811C1C00%0A000701D81FC0FCFFE7E07F03061C00%0A000381588FFFF1FFF3FFFC03003800%0A0003823087FFE3FFF9FFF801807000%0A0001C22301FFFFFFFFFFF018C07000%0A0000E1C630FFFFFFFFFFC03C70E000%0A0000F00C603FFFFFFFFF802601C000%0A00007018C00FFFFFFFFE002B03C000%0A000038308003FFFFFFF80109878000%0A00001C018000FFFFFFC00788070000%0A00001E0300001FFFFE00040E0E0000%0A00000F0601C0007FC00007C01E0000%0A00000780036000000000E3603C0000%0A000003C0026000000001B020780000%0A000001E007CF0300043991C1F00000%0A000080F80449E00000689803E04000%0A0001807C0489B230E64CC807C06000%0A0023203F03993269B244481F003000%0A0066600F801322618266603E039800%0A002C4407E0132670E22600FC016C00%0A00388C03F0026618333C03F00CDE00%0A00011900FE00444993000FE0106600%0A000313C07F800478F0003F80303000%0A000232401FE000000001FF009A1800%0A0001E67807FE0000000FF800CC0000%0A00008FD801FFC000007FF004444000%0A0000091B003FFFC07FFF800666C000%0A000011160007FFFFFFFC0072F30000%0A0000031C0800FFFFFFE00099100000%0A00000210110007FFFC000481880000%0A0000003011700000000076C0800000%0A00000020337200000004C244C00000%0A0000002022674C0001BE8266000000%0A0000000026674CBE8F04D324000000%0A0000000066E64CB08204F11C000000%0A000000002CAA6DB082084180000000%0A0000000018AA753C82084080000000%0A0000000000B6352082087C00000000%0A0000000000363720821B2000000000%0A0000000000002620C31E0000000000%0A000000000000063CFB000000000000%0A000000000000000000000000000000%0A000000000000000000000000000000%0A%0A%5EXA%0A%0A%5EXGR%3ABl_Engel.GRF%5EFS%0A%0A%5EXZ%0A%0A) is a sample how it should look and behave.

Below are the details of my project:

**Input Hexcode** (1890 total bytes, 15 bytes per pixel row in the image)

```
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000FFE0000000000000
000000000000780003800000000000
000000000003000000180000000000
000000000018000000030000000000
0000000000C0021988006000000000
0000000003000F198F801800000000
0000000008000F199F800600000000
00000000200C0F1998010180000000
00000000400E0D999E01C040000000
0000000103C60D999F03F010000000
000000060FC60FD998031008000000
000000080E460FDD98070306000000
0000001006E32CCF3F07E701000000
0000002003F3EC0007064F60800000
00000040033BC000000E0F60400000
0000018603B80000000F1AE0200000
0000030F01F000000003BBC0100000
0000021B01C000FFC000B78F080000
0000043900001FFFFE00271D840000
0000081FE000FFFFFFE00739820000
0000101EE003FFFFFFF80671810000
0000218E701FFFFFFFFE006C008000
00004307003FFFFFFFFF80C638C000
0000472380FFFFFFFFFFC07C784000
0000876101FEF07FFFFFF03CEC2000
000103C607F1C1C07FFFF811C61000
000101EC0FE30300FFF8FC07E41000
0002187C1FC700C31FFC2F06300800
00063E383F80F0F087FF3383018800
00047F1079003FFEC3FFF381878400
000C6380F200FFFFF3FF89C19E0400
0008F0C1E207FFFFFFFFC0E07C0200
00183CC3C3FFFFFFFFFFE0B0700200
00101F83C31FFFFFFFFFF898600100
00100787803FFFFFFFFFFF88300100
00200107807FFFFFFFFFF98C300080
0020000E80FFFE001FFFFC0E000080
0060001C81FFF80003FFFC0E000080
0040001C83FFE00001FFFE0F0000C0
0040003C87FFC000007FFF0D000040
00C000388BFF801E003FFF89800040
00800038E7FF001F001FFF69800060
00800078C7FE003F000FFF39800020
0080007887FC003F000FFF91C00020
008000F80FF8001F0007FF81C00020
018000F80FF8001E0003FF81C00020
010000F81FF01FFFFF03FFC1C00030
010000D83FFFFFFFFFFFFFC1E00010
010100D83FFC0FFFFE0FFFC3600010
010101C85FF000FFE001FFA2603010
010FE1C49FE0007F8001FF9460FC10
0107C1C71FE0003F8001FF9C607C10
030381C31FE0001F0000FF88607810
030281C23FE0001F0000FF88E06810
030001C03FE0001E0000FF80E00010
030001E03FE0001E0000FF80E00010
030001E03FE0000E0001FF81E00010
030001F03FE0000E0001FF81E00010
030001D05FF0000E0001FF83E00010
030001C84FF0000E0001FF06600010
010001C44FF0001E0003FE44E00010
010000C2CFF8001E0003FE48E00030
018000C187F8001E0007FC70E00030
018000E087FC001F0007FC61C00030
018000E007FE001F000FF841C00030
018000F003FE003F001FF803C00030
0180007003FF003F803FF807C00060
00C0007802FF803F807FE80F800060
00C0003E027FE07F80FFD01F800060
00C0003F023FF07FC1FF903F800060
00E0003CC21FFCFFC7FF10E70000C0
0060001E1E0FFFFFFFFE1F0F0000C0
0060001E060FFFFFFFFC1C1E0000C0
00700C0F0107FFFFFFFC103E000180
003018078007FFFFFFF8007C0E0180
00303007C003FFFFFFF800F8138380
00386F03F003F8FFE3F801F830C300
00187603FC07800C003807F03C4300
001C4C81FFFE00E1E00FFFE0060700
000C1B80FC0007CCFC0007C0638600
000E3C007E001F9F3F000F80300E00
000610703F003E7F9F801F811C1C00
000701D81FC0FCFFE7E07F03061C00
000381588FFFF1FFF3FFFC03003800
0003823087FFE3FFF9FFF801807000
0001C22301FFFFFFFFFFF018C07000
0000E1C630FFFFFFFFFFC03C70E000
0000F00C603FFFFFFFFF802601C000
00007018C00FFFFFFFFE002B03C000
000038308003FFFFFFF80109878000
00001C018000FFFFFFC00788070000
00001E0300001FFFFE00040E0E0000
00000F0601C0007FC00007C01E0000
00000780036000000000E3603C0000
000003C0026000000001B020780000
000001E007CF0300043991C1F00000
000080F80449E00000689803E04000
0001807C0489B230E64CC807C06000
0023203F03993269B244481F003000
0066600F801322618266603E039800
002C4407E0132670E22600FC016C00
00388C03F0026618333C03F00CDE00
00011900FE00444993000FE0106600
000313C07F800478F0003F80303000
000232401FE000000001FF009A1800
0001E67807FE0000000FF800CC0000
00008FD801FFC000007FF004444000
0000091B003FFFC07FFF800666C000
000011160007FFFFFFFC0072F30000
0000031C0800FFFFFFE00099100000
00000210110007FFFC000481880000
0000003011700000000076C0800000
00000020337200000004C244C00000
0000002022674C0001BE8266000000
0000000026674CBE8F04D324000000
0000000066E64CB08204F11C000000
000000002CAA6DB082084180000000
0000000018AA753C82084080000000
0000000000B6352082087C00000000
0000000000363720821B2000000000
0000000000002620C31E0000000000
000000000000063CFB000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Output Image**

The image that is output when converting the hexcode:

[image]

**My Approach**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bmpFilePath = "hex_input_image.bmp";
        String pngFilePath = "output.png";

        try {
            // Load the BMP image using ImageIO
            File bmpFile = new File(bmpFilePath);
            if (bmpFile.exists()) {
                BufferedImage bmpImage = ImageIO.read(bmpFile);

                if (bmpImage != null) {
                    // Create a BufferedImage for the PNG image with the same width and height
                    BufferedImage pngImage = new BufferedImage(bmpImage.getWidth(), bmpImage.getHeight(),
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                    // Convert the BMP image to grayscale (monochrome)
                    for (int y = 0; y < bmpImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < bmpImage.getWidth(); x++) {
                            int rgb = bmpImage.getRGB(x, y);
                            int grayValue = (int) (0.299 * ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF) + 0.587 * ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF)
                                    + 0.114 * (rgb & 0xFF));
                            int grayColor = (grayValue << 16) | (grayValue << 8) | grayValue;
                            pngImage.setRGB(x, y, grayColor);
                        }
                    }

                    // Save the PNG image to a file
                    ImageIO.write(pngImage, "PNG", new File(pngFilePath));
                    System.out.println("Conversion completed successfully.");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Failed to load the BMP image.");
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("BMP file does not exist.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Failed to load the BMP image.
```

**Step by step**

- Parse Hexcode: Accept a valid Hexcode input from the user.
- Convert Hexcode to RGB values: Extract the Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha (if available) components from the Hexcode.
- Create an Image: Use the RGB values to create an image in memory.
- Save as JPG/PNG: Save the generated image as a JPG or PNG file.

**Question:** How can I achieve my goal of converting this Hexcode to a JPG or PNG file? 
**Additionally:** Is there a specific file format that comes to mind when you see this hexcode?

Comment: "I have a rough approach, but it doesnt quite work as expected and I dont think its the right path." what is that doesn't work with this approach? That is the actual question that you should be trying to answer before asking anything else. And please don't ask two different things in one question.

Comment: @001 I've utilized an online tool to generate this image, but I lack an understanding of its underlying mechanisms.

Comment: @aled Thank you for your additions, I changed it and added some additional information about what goes wrong, hope now its better

Comment: You have a gap in implementation as you've missed off "Parse Hexcode: Accept a valid Hexcode input from the user.".  You cannot expect `ImageIO.read(bmpFile)` to read a text file of hex codes, it must be supplied with a valid BMP file. If you do supply a bmp image you don't need to process the RGB, just save bmpImage directly to PNG with `ImageIO.write(bmpImage, "PNG", new File(pngFilePath));`

Comment: @DuncG Im providing a BMP file but it doesnt recognize it. I think its not exactly in the BMP format but Im not quite sure.

Comment: @malz You can check BMP format by opening the file with any standard viewer. eg MS Paint on Windows.

Comment: @DuncG Ive provided some additional information about the Hex Code because its indeed ZPL Graphic Hex Code and I think there is some kinda diffrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that protocol, but it appears to use only the 4 least significant bits of each byte.

Here's some example code. I hardcoded the file string for simplicity.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    // Take 4 bits from each char in s and convert to 4 bytes
    static byte[] stringToByteArray(String s)
    {
        byte[] converted = new byte[s.length() * 4];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            byte b1 = (byte)Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
            for (int mask = 0x8; mask != 0; mask >>= 1) {
                converted[j++] = (byte)((b1 & mask) != 0 ? 0 : 255);
            }
        }
        return converted;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String data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
            
        int width = 30 * 4;  // Number of chars per line * 4 bits per char
        int height = 126;    // Number of lines in file

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, stringToByteArray(data));
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File("D:\\temp\\test.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]